# Dictionary of element counts

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary containing `{x,list.count[x]}`. However, I keep running into an error when trying to execute my code:

```
apple = ['variant', 'variant', 'variant2.0', 'variant 3.0']

pear = {}

for x in apple:
    pear.update({x,apple.count(x)})
```

The error is `cannot convert dictionary update sequence element#0 to a sequence.` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apple = ['variant', 'variant', 'variant2.0', 'variant 3.0']
pear = {}
for x in apple:
    pear[x] = pear.get(x, 0) +1
print (pear)
```

Output:

```
{'variant 3.0': 1, 'variant': 2, 'variant2.0': 1}
```

Comment: @AaronHall Thanks very much Aaron.

Comment: i would consider using the .setdefault() method

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error in your dictionary definition.
Try

```
pear.update({x : apple.count(x)})
```

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest a `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> apple = ['variant', 'variant', 'variant2.0', 'variant 3.0']
>>> Counter(apple)
Counter({'variant': 2, 'variant 3.0': 1, 'variant2.0': 1})
```

If you need it in a plain dict afterward:

```
>>> dict(Counter(apple))
{'variant 3.0': 1, 'variant': 2, 'variant2.0': 1}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: @man_ostrich you're quite welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow, you can accept the answer that helped you the most by cilcking the checkmark next to it, and it will add plus 2 to your rep. Cheers!